# Use character "?" in sql query codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3

I have the following SQL query and I want to use the "?" because the postgres 9.5 syntax requires it, the problem is that codeigniter by default uses that symbol to replace values ​​in the SQL query.

```
SELECT codigo, descr, ( select count(*) from "mi_tabla_2" where coddoc::jsonb ? codigo and coddep = '100' and codserie = '50' and codsubserie = '25' ) as check FROM "mi_tabla_1" WHERE std = TRUE
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: This site https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/1964 suggests you can use "??" instead and the PostgresJDBC driver will make the appropriate adaptations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Replace all '?' characters for '$' except the ? required in Postgres syntax

$this->db->bind_marker = '$';//This line change de replacing character for '$'

Exmple

```
$this->db->bind_marker = '$';
$sql = "select count(*) from mi_tabla_2 where coddoc::jsonb ? codigo and coddep = $ and codserie = $ and codsubserie = $";
$this->db->query($sql,array($param1,$param2,$param3));
```